# How do I use letters as variables in a Numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, variables, matrix

I am trying to make the following matrix in Numpy using Colab for an assignment. I want to test if G, a set with this matrix (in which x,y,z are real numbers) and another 3x3 matrix of real numbers, is a group and if it abelian.

```
G_a=np.matrix([[1,x,z],[0,1,y],[0,0,1]])
```

However, I get an error that x is not defined. Can numpy not work with variables?

How would I be able to make this matrix? Do I need to define the variables? How would I define them to just be a stand-in for any real number (if that's possible)?

Thanks

Comment: If by "*a stand-in for any real number*" you mean a symbolic variable, you should look into sympy.

Comment: I saw that elsewhere. The thing is that this is a pretty basic class and the instructor has made it clear not to use any libraries he did not import at the start of the notebook and sympy was not one of them.

Comment: As the library implies, numpy deals only with numerical data. Thought technically you could write x as the string `'x'` and have the matrix have an object dtype.  But whether that could be of an use for your intentions is another thing.

Comment: So I'm guessing you are getting at the fact that a string can't be multiplied, and thus carrying out any operations with this matrix would be moot.

Comment: Exactly. You could define a custom `Variable` object instead, which could handle additions, multiplications and what not by spitting out an `Expression` object, but at that point you'd effectively be reinventing the functionality of sympy. Can you be explicit what your assignment states and what you want to do (with an example and steps for the solution)?

Comment: So here is the link to me trying to figure out how to do this by hand. It's been a while since I math'd and it's tough for me. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4267018/975756

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to answer this specific question with code? Maybe you're supposed to only use python for parts of the assignment with purely numerical computations.

Comment: Also, take into account that I have solved this by hand. So there's no need to review the mathematical concepts unless you want to. I'm just having a hard time coding this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am completely missing your question but to add on to what the commenter has already said, `numpy` is a package that is optimized for numerical calculations. If you wanted to perform a symbolic representation in Python, you'd use `SymPy`.

I am not aware of any rigorous proofs done with strictly numerical calculations, but you could demonstrate properties of what you are trying to prove numerically. For example, we could show that what you found in the Math Stack Exchange is true:

```
import numpy as np
import random as r

# Generate some random numbers
x0 = r.random()*10
y0 = r.random()*10
z0 = r.random()*10
x1 = r.random()*10
y1 = r.random()*10
z1 = r.random()*10

# Define given matrix set
G0 = np.array([[1,x0,y0],[0,1,z0],[0,0,1]])
G1 = np.array([[1,x1,y1],[0,1,z1],[0,0,1]])

# Define property to satisfy
Compare = np.array([[1,x0+x1,x0*z1+y1+y0],[0,1,z0+z1],[0,0,1]])

# Perfom operation
Mult = np.dot(G0,G1)


print(G0)
print('')
print(G1)
print(Mult == Compare)
```

And then you could do a similar code to show that the inverse also satisfies whatever property makes a group Abelian. Doing this for all real numbers with `numpy` wouldn't be possible (as far as I'm aware) because of how the package is made.

I hope that helped.